# How can I track down a Sefer Torah sold many years ago?

Tags: sefer-torah

My grandmother hid a family owned Sefer Torah during the war before she was sent to the camps, and returned after the war to retrieve it from her old house in Hungary. She then took it to Budapest where she was forced to sell it order to pay for her wedding. This was a year or two after the war ended.

Are there any specialist Sefer Torah researchers that could help me locate it, or other records that such transactions would have been recorded on?

Comment: Do you have pictures of it or any identifying features?

Comment: I know her family tree, so if the cover of it still has the old names that may have been stitched into it, that could be the only identifying physical feature.

Otherwise, I will need to rely on the history of the sale itself, to identify it.

Comment: I don't think this is on topic.